# Gathering information about vm's in a resource group

Tags: python, azure-sdk, azure-sdk-python

Would someone be able to share or point to some sample code which basically extracts the information in the following link (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachinesizes/list) from each vm in a resource group? Thanks!

Comment: You need to ask a specific question about code you've written, not a broad, vague question like this.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is your friend:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/azure/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/virtualmachines?view=azure-python

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-compute/azure.mgmt.compute.computemanagementclient?view=azure-python

There is also an official sample page: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/virtual-machines-python-manage/

Hope this helps,